# VBA if Column("A").Cell(i).Value begins with "x" then Column("G").Cell(i).value = "String"

Tags: vba, excel

How can I write this in VBA? I know it's a lot of criteria, but I tried to be thorough.

```
IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with (11*,12*,13*,14*) THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "AIRFRAME"

IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with "35W" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "WIRING"

IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with "34S" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "SOFTWARE"

IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with "32EB" OR "35EB" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "AVIONICS"

IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with "32EF" OR "35EF" BUT <> Cell.Value in Column "TEAM #" (column "H") = "Q3S251" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "AVIONICS"

IF Cell.Value in Column "Job Number" (column "A") begins with "23X" BUT <> Cell.Value in Column "TEAM #" (column "H") = "Q3S251" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "UTILITIES & SUBSYSTEMS"

IF Cell.Value in Column "TEAM #" (column "H") = "Q3S251" THEN cell.value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "FUNCTIONAL TEST"

IF Cell.Value in Column "TEAME NAME" (column "G").ROW(i) = "PROPULSION" THEN Cell.Value = "UTILITIES"
```

Comment: Should it be If the 1st statement and the 2nd and the 3rd etc. then do something or should it be if 1st or 2nd or 3rd then do something? Take a look at `case statements`.

Comment: They are all independent conditions.

Comment: why writing that in VBA instead of putting appropriate formulae in G and H, which is the natural Excel way of working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ScrubSheets()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row in column A
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop for all cells in column A from rows 2 to last row
For myRow = 2 To lastRow
'       First check value of column G
    If Cells(myRow, "G") = "PROPULSION" Then
        Cells(myRow, "G") = "UTILITIES"
    Else
'           Then check column H
        If Cells(myRow, "H") = "Q3S2531" Then
            Cells(myRow, "G") = "FUNCTIONAL TEST"
        Else
 '               Check four character prefixes
            Select Case Left(Cells(myRow, "A"), 4)
                Case "32EB", "35EB", "32EF", "35EF"
                    Cells(myRow, "G") = "AVIONICS"
                Case Else
 '                       Check 3 character prefixes
                    Select Case Left(Cells(myRow, "A"), 3)
                        Case "35W"
                            Cells(myRow, "G") = "WIRING"
                        Case "34S"
                            Cells(myRow, "G") = "SOFTWARE"

                        Case Else
 '                               Check 2 character prefixes
                            Select Case Left(Cells(myRow, "A"), 2)
                                Case "11", "12", "13", "14"
                                    Cells(myRow, "G") = "AIRFRAME"
                             Case "23"
                                    Cells(myRow, "G") = "UTILITIES" & " & " & "SUBSYSTEMS"
                            End Select
                    End Select
            End Select
        End If
    End If
Next myRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'   Message that macro is complete
    MsgBox "Macro complete!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems legit, but you may use 1 select case instead of 2. The readability would improve.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much this is a code, which you can you to start:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim my_cell As Range

    Set my_cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    Select Case True

        Case Left(my_cell, 3) = 11 Or Left(my_cell, 2) = 12:
            my_cell.Offset(0, 5) = "new value 11"
        Case Left(my_cell, 3) = "34S":
            my_cell.Offset(0, 5) = "new value 34S"
        Case Else:
            my_cell.Offset(0, 5) = "case else"
    End Select

End Sub
```

As a next step, make sure that you set `my_cell` correctly and make the conditions and the results the way you want them. Enjoy! :)

Comment: my_cell would be a range so `lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  my_cell=ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1)` correct?

Comment: yup, my cell is a range.